# In-game notification about "game XYZ just releashed a new annoucement..." : how to read it in the SHIFT + TAB Overlay?

Tags: steam

I received an in-game notification :

> "[`game`] just released a new announcement [`announcement's title`]. You can click Shift + Tab to read."

How can I read this very announcement in the SHIFT + TAB Steam overlay without leaving my game? From what I can see, there is no such option despite the notification's suggestion.

(Maybe if I had been quick enough to click on the notification it would open. Next opportunity I'll try then and edit this question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicking the notification should open the page with the news, as you suspected. It doesn't always open in the overlay browser though, and also may not always take you to the proper news page (though Valve has recently revamped the news pages and they seem to work better now with less unrelated garbage articles).